# I find it difficult to use sum()

Tags: php, date, sum

I want to sum the values of a particular column where the date is between the "last Tuesday" and "Today". I wrote this code:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', '****');
define('DB_USER', '****');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_DATABASE', '****');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

    //Sanitize the POST values
$dk=strtotime("today");
$d=strtotime("previous Tuesday");


$res=mysql_query("SELECT sum(mball202) FROM manager WHERE dateid >= date('Y-m-d', $d) AND dateid <= date('Y-m-d', $dk)");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $row['sum(mball202)']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
}
?>
```

but if i run the file, it returns (Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /srv/disk11/1165502/www/tst.scienceontheweb.net/admin/manager/result-weekly.php on line 44
)

What am I doing wrong? Please someone help me.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @Neal, I am a novice, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_error returns false, because thereis an error in you query. You should correct it to :

```
$dateStart = date('Y-m-d', $d);
$dateEnd = date('Y-m-d', $dk);

$res=mysql_query('SELECT sum(mball202) FROM manager WHERE dateid >= "' . $dateStart . '" AND dateid <= "' . $dateEnd . '"');
```

Otherwise, your query is :

```
SELECT sum(mball202) FROM manager WHERE dateid >= date('Y-m-d', 1470693600) AND dateid <= date('Y-m-d', 1470780000)
```

Comment: @NoreplyNoreply make sure to use [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) when you use direct user inputs as parameters. The solution above is secure because `$d` and `$dk` will be converted to a date but in other cases you risk [SQL Injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: @K.Tippenhauer, Okay. I have taken note of that. Thanks.